# VBA For each character and group characters

Tags: string, excel, for-loop, split, vba

I have been working on a project  which is getting a serial number in the context of "J39303", But sometimes there are multiple serials but every time I can guarantee each serial will be 6 letters long, so for example,

J848407888488393 - here is 3 serials just without the J as the start, I want to be able to split it up into 3 separate values, J84840, 78884, 88393,

I have looked at right, mid and left but because the position changes I cannot use these, I am now looking at a For loop to group each 5 characters but have had no luck,

Could someone post me in the right direction,

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Sub mysplit()
    Const SNLength As Integer = 5

    Dim SNs As String
    SNs = "J848407888488393"

    Dim SerialNumber As String
    Dim index As Integer

    If Left(SNs, 1) = "J" Then SNs = Mid(SNs, 2)

    index = 1
    Do While index < Len(SNs)
        SerialNumber = Mid(SNs, index, SNLength)
        MsgBox "J" + SerialNumber
        index = index + SNLength
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to print them to cells grouped together?